# passing ‘const hlp2::Point’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, class, constants, overloading, subscript

I have been encountering an issue where I overloaded the [] operator and I am running into issues when compiling my code.

The overload defintion
`double& Point::operator[](int index) { return index ? y : x; }`

The class Point
`class Point {
public:
// declare constructors (3)
Point();

```
Point(double * arr);

//Point(double x_input, double y_input);

Point(const Point& input);

Point(const double x_input, const double y_input);

// declare overloaded operators (8 member functions)
double& operator[](int index);

Point operator+=(double num);

Point operator+=(const Point& pointee);

Point operator++(int);

Point operator++();

Point operator--(int);

Point operator--();
```

private:
double x; // The x-coordinate of a Point
double y; // The y-coordinate of a Point
};`

The error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPNIR.png)

I am not sure as to why I am encountering this issue and I was hoping if someone can shed some light as to what is happening. Thank you in advance.

I have tried adding const to the overload and its return type but to no avail.

Comment: `double& operator[](int index);` requires a mutable `this`. Think of it as having the implicit signature of `double& operator[](Point* this, int index);`. If you don't need a mutable `this`, mark the member function as `const`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that the `operator []` is called for a constant object of the type `Point` but the operator is not declared as a constant member function.

Add one more overload to the operator

```
// declare overloaded operators (8 member functions)
double& operator[](int index);
const double& operator[](int index) const;
```

If the operator is defined in the global namespace outside the class definition then you need to write

```
const double& hlp2::Point::operator[](int index) const
{
    //,,,
}
```

If the operator is defined in the same namespace where the class is defined then write

```
const double& Point::operator[](int index) const
{
    //,,,
}
```

Shortly speaking define it as you defined the non-constant operator.

Comment: I have added another overload to the operator (declaration and definition pair) but I have this error which does not make sense at all.

point.cpp:61:19: error: no declaration matches ‘const double& hlp2::Point::operator[](int) const’
   61 |     const double& Point::operator[](int index) const
      |                   ^~~~~
point.cpp:56:13: note: candidate is: ‘double& hlp2::Point::operator[](int)’
   56 |     double& Point::operator[](int index)
      |             ^~~~~
point.hpp:15:7: note: ‘class hlp2::Point’ defined here
   15 | class Point {
      |       ^~~~~

Comment: @Daniel It seems you need to define the operator in the global namespace like const double & hlp2::Point::operator[]( int  index ) const { /*,,,*/ }

Comment: Yup that is what I did which is why I am confused as to why there is an error.

Comment: @Daniel II am sorry. I mean in the global namespace. If to define it in the namespace hlp2 then write  const double & Point::operator[]( int index ) cpnst { /*,,,*/ }

Comment: @Daniel Do you have included the operator declaration in the class definition?

Comment: it is declared in the class in the header file and defined with the correct resolution scope. Somehow all the methods have been done the same way and only the const [] overload is having issues. Also, if it is defined in the global namespace, it would not belong to the class and that is not what i intend.

Comment: @Daniel Show the class definition with the two operators excluding all other definitions of its members. And did you recompiled all modules?

Comment: I have edited the post already. Apologies for the delay

Comment: @Daniel Show the code that produces the error and the full error message.

Comment: @Daniel Though it will be much better if you will close the question selecting the best answer and create a new question with your updated code and the new error message.